# NSDate value not accessible across methods

Tags: nsdate

Am sorry to ask such a trivial question. Am a newbie to Objective-C, & simply cannot see how to get this working, after having tried several possible ways & google'd around for it. Please help!
My question is simple. I have a class-level NSDate object, which is declared outside any method in the class as:

```
NSDate *fromDate;
```

Now, within a method, am setting this value to the date from a DatePicker as:

```
fromDate = [datePicker date];
```

Soon after the above assignment, I print its value into the log & it works fine.

```
NSLog(@"From Date: %@", fromDate);
```

Now, when I use NSDate's value in another/different method, the value's gone! Why is it not persisted across methods in the same class itself? What can I do for the value to be accessible across methods?

---

Thanks for your reply.

Hi Remy,

1. I didn't know Objective-C didn't have class-level variables! Thanks for pointing it out!
2. Yes, I've set the project (in Xcode) to do ARC (so, I believe that should take care).
3. Here is the code:

In ViewController.h

```
....
....
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *historyFromDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *historyToDate;
....
....
-(IBAction) fromDateChosen: (id)sender;
-(void) fetchTheHistory;
```

In ViewController.m

```
...
...
@synthesize historyFromDate;
@synthesize historyToDate;
....
....

-(IBAction) fromDateChosen: (id)sender {

NSString *buttonTitle = @"I've chosen the 'FROM' date";

if ([[buttonDateChosen currentTitle] isEqualToString:buttonTitle]) { 

    NSLog(@"User has chosen the 'From' date");

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    // Get the chosen date value
    NSDate *fromDate = [datePicker date];
    historyFromDate = fromDate;



    // Set the 'to' date label to reflect the user's choice
    labelFromDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:historyFromDate];
    NSLog(@"'From' Date Chosen:%@", historyFromDate);
          //[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]]);

    [self fetchTheMoodHistory];
}
}
...
...
...

-(void) fetchTheHistory {

NSLog(@"Calling fetchTheHistory for the period from %@", historyFromDate);
...
...
}

...
...
```

*fromDateChosen* gets called after the user chooses a date form a Date Picker object in the UI.
Within the method '*fromDateChosen*', when I print the *historyFromDate*, the value is correct. 
But, when I print it in *fetchTheHistory* method, the value shows the current date/time (not the one the user chose).

Comment: are you sure you're using ARC? ARC's property uses strong / weak, not the retain keyword !

Comment: @Jean Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? I'm working on an app and I've run into the exact same problem.

Comment: @Jean Never mind, I worked out my problem. I was using `NSCoding` to encode my class and I left out the lines to encode and decode my `NSDate` property.

Answer (score 0):

The date property of `UIDatePicker` is retained by that class, and will be accessible as long as the date picker itself is in scope and valid (not been released). You are storing this date value in a variable, but not retaining it yourself, so when the date picker goes out of scope you lose the value. As a quick fix, do this instead;

```
fromDate = [[datePicker date] retain];
```

Now, this is not the best approach, you really should be making the date a property of whatever class is using this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try put the fromDate variable under class scope, e.g:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSDate *fromDate;
}
```